# Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: android, admob

I'm using  Android Studio. I have added the **googleAdMobAdsdk6-4-1.jar** to the project in my previously added libs folder. I can expand the library file and actually navigate to the AdView class. It compiles with no problem but when I run it It crashes. Any assistance appreciated.

```
12-15 21:35:40.581    5375-5375/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method net.kritico.todolist.ToDoListActivity.onCreate
12-15 21:35:40.581    5375-5375/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 996 (Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdView;) in Lnet/kritico/todolist/ToDoListActivity;
12-15 21:35:40.581    5375-5375/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0037
12-15 21:35:40.585    5375-5375/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2034 at 0x39 in Lnet/kritico/todolist/ToDoListActivity;.onCreate
12-15 21:35:40.585    5375-5375/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0b0b at 0x47 in Lnet/kritico/todolist/ToDoListActivity;.onCreate
12-15 21:35:40.585    5375-5375/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2031 at 0x5c in Lnet/kritico/todolist/ToDoListActivity;.onCreate
12-15 21:35:40.597    5375-5375/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x0b0a at 0x5f in Lnet/kritico/todolist/ToDoListActivity;.onCreate
12-15 21:35:40.765    5375-5375/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-15 21:35:40.765    5375-5375/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa617b908)
12-15 21:35:40.789    5375-5375/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.kritico.todolist/net.kritico.todolist.ToDoListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: I don't know how it is in Android Studio, but in Eclipse you should click right on project ->Properties->Android and on the bottom add library. Maybe in Android Studio is similar

Comment: Admob is now integrated into Play Services. You should use this in new projects going forward. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration

Answer (score 1):

Your XML references com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (see stacktrace) which is contained in the Google Play Services library and is how Admob is now packaged.

But your have included Admob-6.4.1 whcih is the old Admob SDK and the Admob classes there are in a different package and have slightly different signatures.

Remove Admob-6.4.1 from your project and use Google play Services instead.

See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play

Comment: I have done that but now I am getting an error "The Google Play services resources were not found" I am using android studio and all responses about this error on the net are for eclipse.

Comment: How do I add resources in android studio?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: William I have tried that but my Project Structure dialog box has no "Import module" menu option. It only has "+" sign which opens up a New Module dialog. Im using android 0.3.7.

Comment: Sorry that was a poor link. You want to add the Play Services library as a dependency of your module. See the "Adding existing libraries to module dependencies" section of http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#d1112130e248

Answer (score 1):

Remove the jar from your libs folder (That sdk is now deprecated). You should use Google play services.

After removing the jar. Clean your project and add the following under `dependencies` in your app level `build.gradle`.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

Sync your project as prompted after which you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use this latest library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
```

And feel free to read the [admob documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **react-native-admob-next** and seriously I face lot of problems in implementaion

i do just :-

1. npm i react-native-admob-next
2. then open node_modules then find react-native-admob-next/android/build.gradle i
   change dependencies below is code : -

> just add some lines

```
dependencies {
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
// implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
// implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'


implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:+'
}
```